# getByteFrequencyData get accurate data given a time

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-audio

I am looking to get the exact same frequency data given a timestamp. The current code I have results in inconsistent numbers.

```
const renderFromBuffer = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (analyzer) {
      const bufferSource: AudioBufferSourceNode = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
      bufferSource.buffer = source.buffer;
      bufferSource.connect(analyzer);

      bufferSource.onended = () => {
        analyzer.getByteFrequencyData(fftRef.current);
        analyzer.getFloatTimeDomainData(tdRef.current);

        // put on UI
        drawCanvas(
          {
            fft: fftRef.current
          },
          canvasRef.current,
          background,
          type
        );

        // finish
        bufferSource.disconnect();
        resolve("");
      };

      // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode/start
      // maybe I am wrong here, I am offsetting the buffer given the currentTime i.e 3s
      // then I am grabbing 0.01s of audio. The results here seem inconsistent
      bufferSource.start(0, currentTime, 0.01);
    } else {
      reject("analyzer is missing...");
    }
  });
};
```

Initial Frequency Data at 0s

[image: Initial Frequency Data at 0s]

Scrub forward in the timeline, then back to 0s a completely different shape

[image]

Here is how the buffer source is created from audio

```
export const createSource = async (
  mode: "buffer" | "audio",
  audioSource: any,
  audioCtx: AudioContext
) => {
  try {
    const aud = await fetch(audioSource.src);
    const buf = await aud.arrayBuffer();
    const audBuf = await audioCtx.decodeAudioData(buf);

    let source;

    if (mode === "buffer") {
      source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
      source.buffer = audBuf;
    }

    if (mode === "audio") {
      source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audioSource);
    }

    if (!source) throw new Error("source missing");

    source.connect(audioCtx.destination);

    return {
      source
    };
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`Error creating source ${err}`);
  }
};
```

Then you can see inside `renderFromBuffer` a temporary `bufferSource` is created the `source` buffer is assigned to the temporary buffer. Then to get the frequency data I use `bufferSource.start(0, currentTime, 0.01);` but I cannot figure out why this data is coming back inconsistent. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you certain `currentTime` is being reset to 0 when you scrub the time-line? I could easily see cumulative error preventing it in the right (wrong!) circumstances. At 44.1kHz, 0.01 seconds represents just 441 samples. Small deviations in the start time _would markedly_ affect the analyser's output.

Comment: Interesting, the `currentTime` variable is a representation of where the playhead is along the x axis, so when its scrubbed to 1s the offset is 1s, when it moves back it should be 0s. So it does not get reset to 0, same with in the rendering engine. The rendering engine renders the entire video in chunks, so each function gets an offset, the `currentTime` becomes `frame / fps` aka (60 / 60 = 1s). It ends up starting at a disjointed point, then picking back up, so there are weird flickers.

Comment: Perhaps bumping up the `duration` to `0.1s` should return more accurate results?

Comment: perhaps that would be a solution. I've written code to do this stuff years ago and if given the same input file, the output was pixel-identical. EDIT: here's a sample. If you refresh it, two waveforms change, since their synthesis depends on use of the Math.random function. : https://pastebin.com/hkB6n5YU